# Symfony 2 Form - refresh protection when form is not valid

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

first of all sorry for my bad english.
The problem is as follows:

I try to do add and edit post in Blog system.
My pseudocode:

```
private function getPostForm()
{
    $form=$this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add(...
}

public function addPost()
{
   $form=$this->getPostForm... (is a createFormBuilder
   // form to create new post
   // display form to add - send to updatePost
}

public function editPost()
{
   $form=$this->getPostForm... (is a createFormBuilder
   // get post id and display form to edit post
   // send to updatePost
}

public function updatePost()
{
   // get data from post and validate
   $form->bind(...
   // if validate is true => save
   if($form->isValid())....
   // if not => get errors and display
   else { 
   // redirect and display errors and post data
}
```

My problem - when form is not valid, I would like redirect user to add/edit post and display errors thanks to user can't refresh page (eg. F5 key) when data will be sent and not valid.
How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you should do like this. If all is correct do update and redirect, if validation fail display view again

```
public function updatePost()
{
   ....

   if($form->isValid()){
        //yours update logic

       return $this->redirect(..);
   }

   return $this->render('create.html.twig', array(
       'form' => $form->createView();
   ));
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the user can still refresh page and also url address is not correct (eg. post/update instead post/add or post/edit).